# shell : Erase old files

Tags: shell

I Want to execute a shell script to erase old files from a folder.
I wrote this:

```
echo "Début du script Purge WS-- outputs"
find /outillages/output/*.log -type f -exec rm {} + ;
echo "Fin du script Purge WS-- outputs"
```

The problem that it doesn't work !

Can you advice .?

Comment: I tested your script and it works on my computer. Are you receiving any errors? Also, is there any reason why you can't simply use `rm /outillages/output/*.log`?

Comment: Thank you I will test it again

Comment: Nothing happens ! I always find the logs in the Outpout folder, they are not erased :(

Comment: you mean I change my code like this ?:

Comment: echo "Début du script Purge WS-- outputs"



find  rm /outillages/output/*.log



echo "Fin du script Purge WS-- outputs"

Comment: Can you please test it in this format:

Comment: echo "Début du script Purge WS-- outputs"

        find /outillages/output/*.log -name "*.log" -mtime +1 -exec rm -f {} \;

        echo "Fin du script Purge WS-- outputs"

Comment: I mean why not just solely use the `rm` command. So the whole command would be `rm /outillages/output/*.log`